# tuple index out of range error related to curselection (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I have this list:

```
lista=Listbox(root,selectmode=MULTIPLE)
lista.grid(column=0,row=1)                              
lista.config(width=40, height=4)                        
lista.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',selecionado)
```

Attached to this function:

```
def selecionado(evt):
    global ativo
    a=evt.widget
    seleção=int(a.curselection()[0])    
    sel_text=a.get(seleção)
    ativo=[a.get(int(i)) for i in a.curselection()]
```

But if I select something and then deselect, I get this error:

```
    seleção=int(a.curselection()[0])
IndexError: tuple index out of rangeenter code here
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you deselect the item, the function curselection() returns an empty tuple.  When you try to access element [0] on an empty tuple you get an index out of range error.  The solution is to test for this condition.

```
def selecionado(evt):
    global ativo
    a=evt.widget
    b=a.curselection()
    if len(b) > 0:
        seleção=int(a.curselection()[0])    
        sel_text=a.get(seleção)
        ativo=[a.get(int(i)) for i in a.curselection()]
```

[TkInter Listbox docs](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/listbox.html).

Comment: `if len(b) > 0:` could be `if b:`

Answer (score 2):

The @PaulComelius answer is correct, I am giving a variant of the solution with useful notes:

First note is that only  **Tkinter 1.160**  and earlier versions causes the list returned by curselection() to be a list of strings instead of integers. This means you are running **useless** instructions when casting an integer value to an integer value in `seleção=`**int(** `a.curselection()[0]`**)** and `ativo=[a.get(`**int(** i **)**`) for i in a.curselection()]`

Secondly, I would prefer to run:

```
  def selecionado(evt):
        # ....
        a=evt.widget
        if(a.curselection()):
           seleção = a.curselection()[0]  
        # ...
```

Why? Because this is the Pythonic way.

Thirdly and last: Better to run `import tkinter as tk` than `from tkinter import *` .